# Converting certain splitting certain inputs?

Tags: ruby, string, split

I'm writing a program to compute the digital root of an input phrase.  I have the whole digital root algorithm working, but certain input phrases don't seem to mesh well with the `split` method.  I want to separate the input phrase into an array of "characters", or single character strings.

```
puts "Please enter a phrase to be converted"
phrase = gets.chomp.downcase!
phrase = phrase.split("")
```

Whenever the input string does not have any capitalized letters, I get the error `undefined method 'split' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` .  Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `!`

```
puts "Please enter a phrase to be converted"
phrase = gets.chomp.downcase
phrase = phrase.split("")
```

By convention, the method with tailing `!` means altering the receiver rather than create a new copy. [`String#downcase!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-downcase-21) returns `nil` if no character in the String is downcased.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I can see what went wrong now, oops!

Comment: Yep, I was just waiting for the time to pass. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this a few other ways too

```
puts "Please enter a phrase to be converted"
phrase = gets.chomp.downcase.chars.to_a
```

OR **(Although this will be slower due to the iteration over an array it is still faster than `#split`)**

```
puts "Please enter a phrase to be converted"
phrase = gets.chomp.chars.map(&:downcase)
```

Comment: It's better to `downcase` once, rather than iterate over the array and `downcase` each element. I'll add a benchmark.

Comment: @theTinMan I am aware I just like to point out that there are many ways to perform the same task in ruby and unless the string is extremely long the performance impact seems negligible.  but thank you for the benchmarks nice to see one of my methods was the fastest.

Comment: Multiple examples are nice, but it's good to also add caveats when there are some tradeoffs; Newbies won't understand the issue and can end up doing the wrong thing simply "because", such as the selected answer, which, while technically correct, doesn't show a better way. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

@engineersmnky shows two ways to accomplish the same thing, but there is a big difference in the speed between the two:

```
require 'fruity'

phrase = "Please enter a phrase to be converted"

puts "Running chars.to_a vs. split"
compare {
  chars_to_a1 { phrase.chars.to_a }
  split1 { phrase.split("") }
}

puts '-' * 20

puts "Running downcase.chars.to_a vs. chars.to_a.map(&:downcase)"
compare {
  chars_to_a2 { phrase.chomp.downcase.chars.to_a }
  map_downcase { phrase.chomp.chars.to_a.map(&:downcase) }
}
```

Running that results in this output on my laptop:

```
# >> Running chars.to_a vs. split
# >> Running each test 1024 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> chars_to_a1 is faster than split1 by 5x ± 0.1
```

I was surprised that `split` is that much slower in the first test, but it's hard to argue against the numbers.

Piggybacking on that knowledge, I used the faster result to test the result of `downcase` on the string, versus against the individual letters.

```
# >> --------------------
# >> Running downcase.chars.to_a vs. chars.to_a.map(&:downcase)
# >> Running each test 1024 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> chars_to_a2 is faster than map_downcase by 2.4x ± 0.1
```

So, for fastest results use `downcase.chars.to_a`.

---

> Also would like to point out chars.map(&:downcase) is still faster than downcase.split('')...

Here's the additional benchmark:

```
compare {
  chars_to_a2 { phrase.chomp.downcase.chars.to_a }
  map_downcase { phrase.chomp.chars.to_a.map(&:downcase) }
  chars_map { phrase.chomp.chars.map(&:downcase) }
}
# >> Running each test 1024 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> chars_to_a2 is faster than chars_map by 2.4x ± 0.1
# >> chars_map is similar to map_downcase
```

`phrase.chomp.downcase.chars.to_a` still outruns the others by 2x.

It's important to note that using `map` to `downcase` the split string is expensive and will become more expensive the longer the source string becomes. Making the initial string 10x longer allows `phrase.chomp.downcase.chars.to_a` to run 3x faster than the other two.

```
phrase = "Please enter a phrase to be converted" * 10

compare {
  chars_to_a2 { phrase.chomp.downcase.chars.to_a }
  map_downcase { phrase.chomp.chars.to_a.map(&:downcase) }
  chars_map { phrase.chomp.chars.map(&:downcase) }
}
# >> Running each test 128 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> chars_to_a2 is faster than map_downcase by 3.0x ± 0.1
# >> map_downcase is similar to chars_map
```

Comment: Also would like to point out `chars.map(&:downcase)` is still faster than `downcase.split('')` and the conversion of `Enumerable#chars` to an `Array` before map is unnecessary as `Enumberable#map` returns an array when given a `block`

Comment: I was riffing on your code, but will add that as a third test just to show the results.